# Testing serialize/deserialize functions for serde "with" attribute

Tags: testing, rust, serde

Serde derive macros come with the ability to control how a field is serialized/deserialized through the [`#[serde(with = "module")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#with) field attribute. The `"module"` should have serialize and deserialize functions with the right arguments and return types.

[An example that unfortunately got a bit too contrived](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c337eb40f3a390d36bea687ba6082fa):

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Default, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct StringPair(String, String);

mod stringpair_serde {
    pub fn serialize<S>(sp: &super::StringPair, ser: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        ser.serialize_str(format!("{}:{}", sp.0, sp.1).as_str())
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<super::StringPair, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        d.deserialize_str(Visitor)
    }

    struct Visitor;

    impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for Visitor {
        type Value = super::StringPair;

        fn expecting(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "a pair of strings separated by colon (:)")
        }

        fn visit_str<E>(self, s: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
        where
            E: serde::de::Error,
        {
            Ok(s.split_once(":")
                .map(|tup| super::StringPair(tup.0.to_string(), tup.1.to_string()))
                .unwrap_or(Default::default()))
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct UsesStringPair {
    // Other fields ...

    #[serde(with = "stringpair_serde")]
    pub stringpair: StringPair,
}

fn main() {
    let usp = UsesStringPair {
        stringpair: StringPair("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()),
    };

    assert_eq!(
        serde_json::json!(&usp).to_string(),
        r#"{"stringpair":"foo:bar"}"#
    );

    let usp: UsesStringPair = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"stringpair":"baz:qux"}"#).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(
        usp.stringpair,
        StringPair("baz".to_string(), "qux".to_string())
    )
}
```

Testing derived serialization for `UsesStringPair` is trivial with simple assertions. But I have looked at [`serde_test` example](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_test/) as that makes sense to me too.

However, I want to be able to independently test the `stringpair_serde::{serialize, deserialize}` functions (e.g. if my crate provides just `mycrate::StringPair` and `mycrate::stringpair_serde`, and `UsesStringPair` is for the crate users to implement).

One way I've looked into is creating a `serde_json::Serializer` (using `new`, requires a `io::Write` implementation, which I couldn't figure out how to create and use trivially, but that's a separate question) and calling serialize with the created Serializer, then making assertions on the result as before. However, that does not test any/all implementations of `serde::Serializer`, just the one provided in `serde_json`.

I'm wondering if there's a method like in the `serde_test` example that works for ser/deser functions provided by a module.

Comment: Why not derive the two traits directly for `StringPair` itself?

Comment: For your other (implied) question, `&mut Vec<u8>` implements `io::Write`.

Comment: @RuifengXie Several reasons: there could be different ways of to serialize the same time. An example I can think of is `chrono::DateTime<Tz>`. It can be serialized as a string, as a Unix timestamp, as an integer timestamp but with higher resolution (e.g. milliseconds etc.) So the type does itself implement the Serialize, Deserialize traits, but chrono also provides [submodules](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.1/chrono/serde/index.html) that can be used with `with = ...` to serialize `DateTime` value in different ways.

Comment: It could also be that as the crate does not provide the actual type, just a serialization/deserialization format for a type defined elsewhere (can't implement traits or derive on types defined elsewhere). Another, related but different scenario: module writer provides the type, e.g. `StringPair` and it does implement the ser/de traits, but the module writer _also_ wishes to provide ser/de for monadic containers of that type e.g. `Option<StringPair>` gets serialized differently from `StringPair`. Lots of reasons for needing a stand-alone ser/de module instead of type implementing traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method within `serde_test` that can test these functions directly. While `serde_test` uses its own `Serializer` and `Deserializer` internally, it does not expose these types, so you can't use them directly in your testing.

However, you can accomplish this with the [`serde_assert`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_assert) crate (disclaimer: I wrote `serde_assert`). `serde_assert` directly exposes its `Serializer` and `Deserializer` specifically for testing, and works well for your use case:

```rust
use serde_assert::{Deserializer, Serializer, Token, Tokens};

#[test]
fn serialize() {
    let serializer = Serializer::builder().build();

    assert_eq!(
        stringpair_serde::serialize(
            &StringPair("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()),
            &serializer
        ),
        Ok(Tokens(vec![Token::Str("foo:bar".to_string())])),
    );
}

#[test]
fn deserialize() {
    let mut deserializer = Deserializer::builder()
        .tokens(Tokens(vec![Token::Str("foo:bar".to_string())]))
        .build();

    assert_eq!(
        stringpair_serde::deserialize(&mut deserializer),
        Ok(StringPair("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()))
    );
}
```